# How to place button over another on vuetify

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm trying to place a button on a clickable card, but when I press the button, the card is also clicked.
My code looks like this:

```
<v-card @click="show = !show">
   <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/sunshine.jpg"></v-img>
   <v-btn color="primary" @click="doSomething = !doSomething">Click me!</v-btn>
</v-card>
```

How can I resolve this problem? thanks

Comment: Use `stop` modifier on click event in order to prevent event bubbling
`<v-btn color="primary" @click.stop="doSomething = !doSomething">Click me!</v-btn>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In vue you can use `stop` modifier

```
    <v-card @click="show = !show">
   <v-img src="https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/cards/sunshine.jpg"></v-img>
   <v-btn color="primary" @click.stop="doSomething = !doSomething">Click me!</v-btn>
</v-card>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to stop the click event propagation once the button is clicked. Or else the parent click will also be triggered.

```js
function buttonCkicked(event) {
  console.log('Button Clicked');
  event.stopPropagation();
}

function parentClicked(event) {
  console.log('Parent Clicked');
}
```

```html
<div style="border: 1px solid blue; padding: 50px" onclick="parentClicked(event)">
  <h1>Container Div</h1>
  <button onclick="buttonCkicked(event)">Click Me</button>
</div>
```

In `Vue JS` you can achieve this using @click.stop event. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/354ud9rn/).